# sqlite3 disk I/O error on cli

Tags: sqlite

sqlite version 3.6.20, running through VNC.

Starting sqlite3 cli session. When trying to run commands ".tables", ".databases", "create table" I get "Error: disk I/O error". I don't know how to get more accurate description. I want to write in my home directory where I have permissions.

I tried some suggested fixes in .sqliterc with journal mode and temp storage - they do not help. Some commands like "PRAGMA synchronous = OFF;" also cause disk io error.

```
.output /dev/null
PRAGMA journal_mode = MEMORY;
PRAGMA locking_mode = EXCLUSIVE;
PRAGMA temp_store_directory = '/home/username/tmp';
```

How to find out more about error and solve this?

Comment: `.log stderr` (which might need a newer version)

Comment: .log stderr does not work in version 3.6.20. I cannot upgrade and cannot use new local version since it's linked against different glibc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was VMWARE related error. Solution: move files to /tmp. Sqlite works there.
It is described here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/93575/sqlite-disk-i-o-error-3850

Comment: If I could give you more rep for this answer, I would. Thank you!